# reshape wide to long in stata but new variable contains all missing values

Tags: stata, reshape

I need to `reshape` a dataset, whose original form is as follows:

```
schid     m2s1q0_i     m2s1q0_ii    ...     m2s1q0_x
1            6            2                   3
```

[image: data screenshot]
I want to `reshape` it into the long format, like this:

```
schid teacher_id
1        5
1        2
...      
1       3
```

I used this code:

```
reshape long m2s1q0_, i(schoolid) j(teacher_id)
```

However, the `teacher_id` variable is all missing. Where did it go wrong?

Comment: From the `help reshape`, there is an options string

Answer (score 3):

If you use the option `string` teacher ids will be generated as string variables rather than missing. You can then use `encode` to create numeric values for the teacher_id variable

Here is an example:

```
clear
set obs 10
gen schid = _n
gen m_i = 1
gen m_ii = 2
gen m_iii = 3
reshape long m_, i(schid) j(teacher_id) string
encode teacher_id, gen(teacher_id2)
```